# add temporary integer column to table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to add a temporary column with a default integer value of 0.

```
Playlist.select("playlists.*, 0 AS point_count")
```

this is pretty much what I want, the only difference is I want the 0 to be an int, not a string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`Playlist.select("playlists.*, CAST(0 AS integer) AS point_count")`

Comment: This still saves, or at least returns as a string.

Comment: The problem is that Rails doesn't know what type `point_count` should be so `p.point_count.class` will be `String` when it should be `Fixnum` on the Ruby side of things.

Comment: @muistooshort is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Ya I was thinking that. The problem is I want them all to be 0 so I can increment some of them and then sort.